# Scraping data with Python and BeautifulSoup - can't extract div attribute content

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to extract some data from a website using Python and BeautifulSoup. 
I can't seem to find a way to extract the content of the div attributes.

For example, from this:

```
<div class= "something">
    <div class="a" title="b">
        <img class="c" height="d" src="e" width="f" alt="g">
    </div>
```

I'd like to extract the title and get the result:

```
b
```

I tried with this:

```
for all_data in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'someClass'}):
    for headline in all_data.find_all('div', {'class': 'main-
     attributes'}):

        for rating in headline.find('div', {'class': 'Something'}):
            print(rating)
```

Now this of course pulls out the entire div class. What I want is to pull out just the title.
The other thing is when I try to write this entire div class to a CSV it either writes a blank or just messes up the entire CSV.

I'd really appreciate any sort of help with this. I'm a total beginner in Python and coding so I'm sorry if this question is not specific enough.

Thanks in advance!!
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `find()` returns a single element and not a list. So, you **can't iterate** over it like this:

   ```
   for rating in headline.find('div', {'class': 'Something'}):
       print(rating)
   ```
2. To get the`title` attribute, you can simply use **`['title']`** on the soup object like this:

   ```
   >>> html = '''<div class= "something">
   <div class="a" title="b">
       <img class="c" height="d" src="e" width="f" alt="g">
   </div>'''
   >>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

   >>> soup.find('div', class_='something').div
   <div class="a" title="b">
   <img alt="g" class="c" height="d" src="e" width="f"/>
   </div>

   >>> soup.find('div', class_='something').div['title']
   'b'
   ```

Or, to be more precise, you can use

```
soup.find('div', class_='something').find('div', class_='a')['title']
```

[Read the docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) for learning more on how to get attributes / contents of attributes.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, it worked and I got out the title attribute. The problem now is that the output looks like this `['s']['o']['m']['e']['t']['h']['i']['n']['g']`and it's printed vertically. I can't access it like a list, can't concatenate it and can't turn it in a list.  If I try to export it to a cvs it just messes it up, or it just writes the last character, so 'g' in this case. I know I'm missing something but I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: In your question you stated that your expected output was *b* (ie. the title). I don't know what code you've written now, but why are you printing *something* (ie. the class name)?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I want to print out the title, but as it's composed out of more than 1 character  it prints out every character in it separately and vertically. When I try to write it to a csv it just writes the last character in the title. I hope it makes sense now. thanks for the help

Comment: That must be happening because you're using a `for` loop on the `find()` method. Don't use the loop, just print it directly.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! IT'S WORKING!!!! YEEEAAAAH! :D thanks mate, couldn't have done it without your help. have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract `title` of element with class `a` you can do something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ad= '<div class= "something"> \
        <div class="a" title="b"> \
           <img class="c" height="d" src="e" width="f" alt="g"> \
        </div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(ad,"lxml").find_all("div", {"class": "a"})
for items in soup:
    title=items['title']     #this format is used to fetch attributes of an element
    print(title)
```

Comment: Might as well go for `.find_all('div', class_='a', title=True)` to make sure the elements actually have a title attribute present as well as the class...